# adding class to array elements through loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, delay, addclass

I need the loop that checks input fields from 'inputs' array, and if there are empty fields, special dialog need to be displayed near them, and after the dialog is displayed I need class 'style' to be added to the input field near which the dialog was displayed, then dialog should go to the next emppty field and add class 'style' to it. And so on until all empty inputs have class 'style'.

The problem is, in my loop after the dialog is displayed class 'style' is added only to the last element from the array, but it should be added to every empty element with delays in between.

This is my loop, but as I said it is not working properly:

```
for(i=0;i<inputs.length;i++){
var now = inputs[i];
var top = inputs[i].attr('top');
    if(!now.val()){
    if(dialog.css('display')=='none'){now.addClass('style');dialog.css('top',top).fadeIn(200);}
    else{dialog.delay(300).animate({"top": top}, 500, function(){now.addClass('style');});
    }else{now.removeClass('style');}}
```

P.S. Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because the function that is calling 'addClass' is happening after the 300 millisecond animation. By that time, the value of the 'i' variable has changed because the for loop will continue to run.

You may just be able to have the 'now.addClass' call before the 'animate' and delay. Otherwise, you will have to break the loop and continue after the animation is complete to prevent the variable from being overwritten.

Here is an example of what I was talking about. The code below will process 1 input at a time and not continue to the next until the current one is finished processing (this code has not been tested):

```
var offset = -1;

var inputs = (something goes here)

iterateInputs();

function iterateInputs()
{
    offset++;

if (typeof inputs[offset] != 'undefined')
{
    eachInput();
}
else
{
    // all done!
}
}

function eachInput()
{
var now = inputs[offset];
var top = inputs[offset].attr('top');
if (!now.val())
{
    if (dialog.css('display')=='none')
    {
        now.addClass('style');
        dialog.css('top', top).fadeIn(200, function(){
            iterateInputs();
        });
    }
    else
    {
        dialog.delay(300).animate({"top": top}, 500, function(){
            now.addClass('style');
            iterateInputs();
        });
    }
}
else
{
    now.removeClass('style');
    iterateInputs();
}
}
```